# Textbook for learning analog IC design?

Tags: integrated-circuit, analog, design, books

I am currently using Carusone's "Analog Integrated circuit design", but this book seems more suited as a reference book for professionals who already know the subject. Are there any good alternatives to this book?

Comment: This weeks best answer will be wrong in a week or a year hence this question is unsuitable for this site. Please read the rules on setting questions.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products are off-topic in this forum.  Reference: Help->Tour->Don't ask about...Shopping or buying recommendations.

Comment: I think asking for textbook recommendations (essentially, a reference request) is completely different to asking about which specific components to buy for a particular project. Do design methods for analog ICs really change drastically on a week-to-week or year-to-year timescale, like the availability and features of the specific ICs made using them? I doubt it. And how can a book recommendation *not* be based on a reference? Hence, I disagree with the closure of this question.

Comment: here is a good one: http://www.eevblog.com/files/seekPDF.pdf

Comment: @OleksandrR. - Questions seeking book recommendations are historically closed in most (if not all) of SO/SE. Besides being a special kind of shopping question, they can also be classified as *opinion based* (regarding what one consider *good*) and *too broad* (as literature may be sometimes very extensive on the subject). That's why these questions are not a good fit for a strict Q&A site like ours.

Comment: @Ricardo well, suit yourself. Certainly such questions are not closed in *all* of SE. For example: [What *Mathematica* book to buy?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5059/), [*Mathematica* Reference Book on Reliability Engineering?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40409/), [Is there a free version of the Springer book “Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica”?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50826/), [Book about using Mathematica in real world engineering projects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59983/), amongst others.

Comment: @Ricardo of course each site has its own customs and I am not suggesting that what works for *Mathematica*.SE will necessarily work here. But it is far from necessary that all such questions be closed pre-emptively on the assumption that they are ill-defined or will not receive good answers. I am sure you know very well the justification for not allowing shopping questions, and as I mentioned above, it is not applicable in the same way to reference requests. It would not be helpful for "no shopping questions!" to become simply a dogma, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are way too many possible answers to this question.  But I can give you a really great starting point:

Hans R. Camenzind was the inventor of the 555 timer chip.  According to his website, he has designed 151 standard and custom ICs so far.

He published several books over his lifetime.  One of the best is available as a free download.

The book that I'm recommending that you read is titled "Designing Analog Chips".  [The website is](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/) and here is a direct [Link to PDF book](http://www.designinganalogchips.com/_count/designinganalogchips.pdf)

I found the book to be extremely informative.

Comment: I'll go even further in my recommendation for the book "Designing Analog Chips" - it is fabulous!  I just started reading it again - Mr. Camenzind starts with the basics of how semiconductors work and then heads into SPICE.  All of this is in extremely easy-to-understand language.